# Is there any keyboard shortcut list for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to find some keyboard shortucts for phpMyAdmin.
To execute any query, I must go to the mouse, click on a button, and go back to the keyboard.
I can't find any shortcut list, even on documentation page.

Comment: If there is `no way` - that also could be the answer. Or, I should delete the question ?

Comment: No, can be answer and deleting your question is not good idea. Otherwise someone else, who have same question, have to google it again and probably ask it here again also.

Answer (score 24):

`Ctrl + Enter` works for me to submit SQL query without need to use a mouse.

Answer (score 4):

Currently phpMyAdmin supports following shortcuts:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - Submit query

<kbd>k</kbd> - Toggle console

<kbd>h</kbd> - Go to home page

<kbd>s</kbd> - Open settings

<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> - Go to database structure (Provided you are in database related page)

<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> - Search database (Provided you are in database related page)

<kbd>t</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> - Go to table structure (Provided you are in table related page)

<kbd>t</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> - Search table (Provided you are in table related page)

<kbd>backspace</kbd> - Takes you to older page.

Source: [phpMyAdmin docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#shortcut-keys)

Comment: A shortcut is missing how to refresh the query (not the page). CTRL + R reloads the page and kills the latest executed query. 'R' for refresh query had been nice, but it is not implemented yet. – Which leaves us with 1. Copy your query before refreshing, 2. Use query history, 3. Export the query...

Answer (score 2):

there is no short keys for PHPMyAdmin i think but there is some short keys in [MysqlWorkBench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) .

Comment: Helpful Tip: Ctrl+Shift+Enter is the combo to execute SQL commands in MysqlWorkBench.

Comment: This is not true.  You can navigate cells with Control+direction arrow, and as the answer above states you can submit an SQL query with Control+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the bottom left, you should have a tab named 'Console', it will open a console like interface in your browser and will allow you to interact with the system using (mostly) your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Well-spotted.  It ain't perfect but it's a start. Also "k" seems to toggle it.

Answer (score 2):

Recently they added support for shortcuts. Please refer https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#shortcut-keys

Answer (score 2):

`Alt+Enter` also works for run a query. And use `Backspace` to go older page.

Answer (score 1):

Press Tab and then Enter.

Pressing Tab moves cursor to the delimiter field and pressing Enter in that field executes the query. (phpMyAdmin 3.4.11)

Answer (score 0):

Latest Versions of PHPMyAdmin support  `Ctrl + Enter` and `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use shift and arrow keys when you are creating columns to move between the columns, so you do not have to use mouse or tab a bunch of times.

So if multiple columns are showing, and you are in first name field, pressing shift and down arrow will take you to the second column